# All Library's installed with pip disappear when pulling my repo to another location?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I'm using ubuntu 15.04, every time I pull one of my repos from bitbucket to another location on my computer I can't run the program because I get a Import Error. I then try using pip freeze then I get this error

```
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 22, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/freeze.py, line 74, in run
    req = pip.FrozenRequirement.from_dist(dist, dependency_links, find_tags=find_tags)
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 299, in from_dist
    assert len(specs) == 1 and specs[0][0] == '=='
AssertionError
Storing debug log for failure in /home/josh//.pip/pip.log
```

The virtualenv that got pulled with the repo is activated when I try to run the program/pip freeze

Comment: you probably don't want to store your virtualenv in the repo - google around for some strong opinions on the subject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path of the project root is hardcoded when the virtual environment is initiated.  Recreate your virtual environment if the project root is different.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that all 3rd party Librarys that were installed with the project have to reinstalled anytime someone wants to work on the project? Doesnt this make things difficult when working on a project on a team? I thought that was somewhat of the purpose of a virtualenv @scytale

Comment: @Groovietunes You wouldn't typically store a virtual environment in the repo.  Add your dependencies to a 'requirements.txt' file and new team members can `pip install -r requirements.txt' after creating their own virtual environment specific to their machine.